# When using heroku container:release -a MyApp web I get error: process type already running the specified docker image

Tags: docker, heroku

I'm using Heroku with Docker. When pushing my image with:

```
heroku container:release -a MyApp web
```

My console returns:

> The process type web was not updated, because it is already running
>   the specified docker image

Someone knows what going on here ? I have never pushed this image in my app.

Any hint would be great.

Comment: How are you pushing the image?

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU as following, `docker push registry.heroku.com/$1/$2`

Comment: Please put the full output from your push. This error indicates Heroku can't find a new image for your web process type. So it seems you're either pushing an image which was already released, or you're pushing to the wrong tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to build the images, before pushing it.

so run this command:

```
heroku container:push web --app application-name
```

and then try to run

```
heroku container:release  web --app application-name
```